# How to convert this string to an array of integers?

Tags: c#

I have `string s = "158,141,90,86";`

How I can convert them into int[]?

Comment: DO you want 4 elements in the Int[] array?

Comment: @saurabh: As opposed to?

Comment: @Steve Townsend: Is this similar to ET.PhoneHome()?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
int[] result = "158,141,90,86".Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 17):

Like this, with LINQ:

```
int[] array = s.Split(',')
               .Select(x => int.Parse(x))
               .ToArray();
```

Note that that will throw an exception if any element of the text isn't an integer. If you want to make it more resilient (if this is user-entered data for example) you'll need to use `int.TryParse`; at that point life becomes a bit more complicated in terms of the LINQ query.

EDIT: To make it parse to an `int?[]` (with a null value corresponding to each invalid substring) you could do something like:

```
int?[] array = s.Split(',')
                .Select(x => { 
                      int value;
                      return int.TryParse(x, out value) ? value : (int?)null;
                 })
                .ToArray();
```

As I said, it's not terribly nice :(

EDIT: In the comments, Dan commented on the "obsession" with the above approach instead of (presumably) a more imperative approach. In my view even the less-pleasant second version is still easier to read than the imperative alternative. The ugliness is only due to the ugly nature of `int.TryParse`, which is no less ugly when used in imperative code.

If `int.TryParse` either returned `int?` or `Tuple<bool, int>` then it would be as easy as the first version. Even converting from the tuple form to the nullable form would be simple, with one extra projection:

```
int[] array = s.Split(',')
               .Select(x => int.TryParseTuple(x))
               .Select(tuple => tuple.First ? tuple.Second : (int?) null)
               .ToArray();
```

Comment: For completeness how would it change if you had to try and parse the int?

Comment: @Chloe: To do that "right", you'd want to change it to an array of `int?`.

Comment: In his answer, Grif claims this produces an error.  I admit I haven't tried it, but do you maybe need to replace with `return int.TryParse(x, out value) ? (int?) value : null` so that both branches of your conditional have the same type?

Comment: OK, I did just try it, and it looks like casting *either* branch of the conditional to `int?` will do.

Comment: Why the obsession with trying to do it all in one line, even at the expense of readability? (This is not just at Jon, but all the answers seem to fall into this).

Comment: @Dan: I regard this as more readable than the alternatives, to be honest. Editing to reflect that...

Comment: @Dan: At risk of agreeing with Jon, you have to admit that this functional approach is elegant and flexible.

Comment: @Jon I normally do agree functional versions can be more readable, but this seems to be stretching it. I think it's the inclusion of conditional logic within the functional approach that seems a bit "wrong". However, you may well be right this is due to the ugliness of `int.TryParse()` (I've read your C# in Depth book and like the way you use nullable types to perform this in a novel and "nicer" way).

Answer (score 1):

An imperative solution would of course be:

```
        string[] sa = s.Split(',');
        int?[] array = new int?[sa.Length];
        int value;
        for (int i = 0; i < sa.Length; i++)
            if (int.TryParse(sa[i], out value))
                array[i] = value;
            else
                array[i] = null;
```

Comment: @Andrey: Ahh yes. Not much better than my code in this case, but might be very useful in other situations. Good to know it's possible. Thanks.

Comment: @Grif: It would have been helpful to have added a comment to my answer to let me know, rather than adding your own answer. I've fixed it.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Somehow I don't seem to be able to do so. Or am I missing something? (Low Rep?)

Comment: @Grif: Yes, you need 50 rep to comment on other people's answers.

Comment: @Grif: Ah, that makes sense - sorry for the inappropriate suggestion. I forget about things like that :(

Comment: @Grif: You could probably shorten this. For example, the default is `null`, so you can skip the `else` clause entirely. Still, it's a viable, non-LINQ solution, so I'm glad to upvote it (and help you get enough rep to use the comment feature).

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with LINQ/int?[] is:

```
return source.Split(',') 
                .Select(x => {  
                      int? value = null; 
                      int parsed;
                      if (int.TryParse(x, out parsed)) {
                          value = parsed;
                      }
                      return value; 
                 }) 
                .ToArray();
```